# Prove $\mathbb{E}[X_t | \mathcal{F}_s] = \mathbb{E}[X_t | \sigma(\mathcal{F}_s \cup \mathcal{G}_s)] $

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

We want to prove that if  $X_t$ is an $\mathcal{F}_t$ - martingale:  $\mathbb{E}[X_t | \mathcal{F}_s] = X_s$ for $s<t$,  then it's also a $\sigma(\mathcal{F}_s \cup \mathcal{G}_s)$- martingale. $\mathcal{F}_t \perp \mathcal{G}_t $ are filtrations.

The proof I was given involves choosing $F \in \mathcal{F}_t$ and $G \in \mathcal{G}_t$ and proving that

\begin{equation}
\int_{F \cap G} \mathbb{E}[X_t | \mathcal{F}_s] dP = \int_{F \cap G} X_s dP
\end{equation}
and then claiming that $\sigma( \{F \cap G :F \in \mathcal{F}_t, G \in \mathcal{G}_t \} ) = \sigma(\mathcal{F}_t \cup \mathcal{G}_t)$. $\square$

I thought of a different (and more elegant) way, using the Tower property of expectations. Since we know that $\mathcal{F}_t \subset \sigma(\mathcal{F}_s \cup \mathcal{G}_s)$, then

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X_t | \sigma(\mathcal{F}_s \cup \mathcal{G}_s)] &=\mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}[X_t | \sigma(\mathcal{F}_s \cup \mathcal{G}_s)] | \mathcal{F}_s] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[X_t | \mathcal{F}_s]\\
&= X_s  \space \square \\
\end{align}

is my reasoning correct?

Comment: How do you obtain the first equality in your reasoning?

Comment: that's the Tower property

Comment: It is? The tower property usually refers to the property: ${\rm E}[{\rm E}[X\mid\mathcal{G}]]={\rm E}[X]$.

Comment: you mean that I can't do $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E} [X |\mathcal{F}] |\mathcal{G}] = \mathbb{E}[X | \mathcal{F}]$ ?

Comment: I might be misusing it, we've done $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E} [X_t |\mathcal{F}_t] | \mathcal{F}_s] = \mathbb{E}[X_t | \mathcal{F}_s] $ for $s<t$ and $X_t$ martingale. But that was the same filtration. But since $\mathcal{F}_t \subset \sigma(\mathcal{F}_t \cup \mathcal{G}_t)  $ I thought it might work here as well.

Comment: Since $\mathcal{F}_s\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{F}_s\cup\mathcal{G}_s)$ you can conclude that ${\rm E}[{\rm E}[X_t\mid \sigma(\mathcal{F}_s\cup\mathcal{G}_s)]\mid\mathcal{F}_s]={\rm E}[X_t\mid \mathcal{F_s}]$ but not the other way around.

Comment: One should probably mention (to complete Stefan's much to-the-point explanations) that the result does not hold in general, in particular the independence property of the filtrations is crucial, hence every "proof" failing to use this property has to be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\mathcal{F}_s\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{F}_s\cup\mathcal{G}_s)$ you can conclude that
$$
{\rm E}[{\rm E}[X_t\mid\sigma(\mathcal{F}_s\cup\mathcal{G}_s)]\mid\mathcal{F}_s]={\rm E}[X_t\mid\mathcal{F}_s]
$$
but you certainly *cannot* conclude that
$$
{\rm E}[{\rm E}[X_t\mid\sigma(\mathcal{F}_s\cup\mathcal{G}_s)]\mid\mathcal{F}_s]={\rm E}[X_t\mid\sigma(\mathcal{F}_s\cup\mathcal{G}_s)]
$$
which is what you did in your first equality. This would require that $\sigma(\mathcal{F}_s\cup\mathcal{G}_s)\subseteq \mathcal{F}_s$ which in general does not hold.